# Properties DB difference for RVT and DWFX

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are using SQLite properties database from Model Derivative API for properties processing. Previously we were using it with IFC, Revit and Inventor models, it was ok. But with DWFX format we faced with a problem that SQLite database structure is different (images attached). 'display_precision' column is missing in the '_objects_attr' table and '_objects_ercv' table additionally presented. The question is how to handle data from '_objecta_ercv' table and is it possible that we'll face with another structure for some specific file format?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the precision field is optional and was introduced later in the SVF translation workflow which the SQLite DB is an output from. The precision field is also optional in the .json.gz files that the Viewer is using.

The ercv table is a legacy table and only be present for .dwfx and should be empty.

Comment: thank you, Cyrille! we'll change our processing a bit then